# SQL join query median

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a query with two joined tables and I want to return median from one column as a result.

Query looks like this:

`select table1.column1, count(distinct(table2.column2)) 
 from table1 left join 
 table2 on table1.column1 = table2.column4
 where column3 = 1 
 group by table1.column1`

And results looks like this(there is more lines ofc):

`|   column1  | column2 |
 +------------+---------+
 |    111     |    4    | 
 |    222     |    5    |
 |    333     |    5    |
 |    444     |    5    |`

And I want to pull out median from column2 results.

Is there any way to do it without major modifications in this query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to calculate median with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `percentile_disc()`:

```
select percentile_disc(0.5) over (order by cnt)
from (select table1.column1, count(distinct table2.column2) as cnt
      from table1 left join
           table2
           on table1.column1 = table2.column4
      where column3 = 1
      group by table1.column1
     ) t
```

Answer (score -1):

Please create the function below to get the median:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _final_median(NUMERIC[])
   RETURNS NUMERIC AS
$$
   SELECT AVG(val)
   FROM (
     SELECT val
     FROM unnest($1) val
     ORDER BY 1
     LIMIT  2 - MOD(array_upper($1, 1), 2)
     OFFSET CEIL(array_upper($1, 1) / 2.0) - 1
   ) sub;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;

CREATE AGGREGATE median(NUMERIC) (
  SFUNC=array_append,
  STYPE=NUMERIC[],
  FINALFUNC=_final_median,
  INITCOND='{}'
);
```

Example usage: `SELECT median(num_value) AS median_value FROM t;`

Specific for you, based on the question:

```
select t.*,median(column2) as median_value
from (
      select table1.column1, count(distinct(table2.column2)) as column2
      from table1 left join 
      table2 on table1.column1 = table2.column4
      where column3 = 1 
      group by table1.column1
     ) t
```

Reference: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Median

More examples: [How do i get min, median and max from my query in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067656/how-do-i-get-min-median-and-max-from-my-query-in-postgresql)