# Find median without using window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, olap

I have a dataset with columns - customer, product, and quantity.
I want to find the median of quantity with respect to different products. Assuming we need to work only for an odd number of rows.

Functions like With, Join, aggregate functions like count, avg, max, min, etc are allowed. A solution using nested subqueries would be ideal for this question.

So far I have listed down the quantity and product in sorted order and found the median number using ROUND((COUNT(QUANT) / 2) + 1) and now I need to find that median row without using any window function.

Input

| Product | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 6 |
| B | 7 |
| C | 11 |
| C | 13 |
| C | 15 |
| D | 4 |
| D | 5 |
| D | 6 |

Output

| Product | Median |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 6 |
| C | 13 |
| D | 5 |

Comment: How do you expect to calculate something without using any functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "now I need to find that median row" ? The median is a calculated value according to your formula, this value may not correspond to any row in your table, so what should be the median row ?

Comment: [SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY x) FROM t;](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40317116/5298879) is a simpler way to get median but as @Edouard says, it might not correspond to any row. If you had 4 rows with values 1,2,3,4, their median is 2.5 - there is no row with 2.5 in it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry I should have been clear I cannot use any functions like rownumber or percentile or anything direct.

Comment: If you can't use any function you can't even use `count()` or `round()` so this whole question makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Edouard with the example I have given in the post I know that I have to select 2nd value for each product but with that information, I cannot go over the table and select the median value

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no functions with rownumber or percentile. aggregate functions, group by, count, round  and joins is fine.

Comment: What wrong with using window functions if that solves your problem?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can't use that according to the spec sheet that's the reason I am reaching out here.

Comment: @Zegarek Sorry I should have been clear on this. We can make a solution based on odd number of rows.

Comment: @John What about `join`, `where`, `limit`, `offset`, [`with` cte](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-with.html)? What about subqueries? Are all [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-window.html) forbidden? Please clarify your constraints and assumptions about input data in the question. Some rationale behind those constrains would be helpful as well

Comment: @Zegarek We can use the functions that you have mentioned. As for the window functions mentioned here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-window.html I cannot use that directly however implementation of these functions is allowed in some other way like defining your own index is possible. As this is part of an assignment that's the reason for these constraints. Subqueries are fine too.

Comment: Usage of window functions can usually be replaced by self join on the table.

Comment: @Edouard I did try to do that but I am really stuck on how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two solutions where *prod* is the name of your table :

**Solution 1 with Window function**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.Product)
       t.Product
     , nth_value(t.Quantity, m.median) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Product ORDER BY Quantity ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS median_Qty
  FROM prod AS t
 INNER JOIN
     ( SELECT Product, round(count(*)/2+1) :: integer AS median
         FROM prod
        GROUP BY Product
     ) AS m
    ON m.Product = t.Product
```

**Solution 2 without Window function**

This solution is based on the `SELECT ... LIMIT 1 OFFSET median` query where *median* is a value only known at the run time, so this query must be implemented as a dynamic statement within a plpgsql function whose input parameter is the Product :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION median_quantity(INOUT myProduct varchar(1), OUT Median_Quantity integer)
RETURNS setof record LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
  median integer ;
BEGIN
    SELECT round(count(*)/2) :: integer
      INTO median
      FROM prod
     WHERE Product = myProduct ;
     
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE E'
    SELECT Product, Quantity
      FROM prod
     WHERE Product = ' || quote_nullable(myProduct) || '
     ORDER BY Quantity
     LIMIT 1
     OFFSET ' || median ;
END ;
$$ ;
```

The expected result is given by the query :

```
SELECT m.myProduct, m.Median_Quantity
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (Product)
              Product
         FROM prod
     ) AS p
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL median_quantity(p.Product) AS m
```

All the details in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d3e66f32e13487e63ab4e210f34d33d3)