# Any ideas on how to calculate median in Postgresql using count with sum?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I know how to find Median with just using row_number, but have no idea how to find it only using sum, count

Comment: [How do I get min, median and max from my query in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12067656/1995738)

Comment: @klin I cannot use percentile.

Comment: You do not have to. Find the code of the `median()` function in the linked answers.